# How do I POST noUiSlider values along with the rest of my form?

Tags: php

I have a noUiSlider with 2 handles, a min and max age, inside my form.

If I `var_dump($_POST)` the form, only the sex_select value is returned.

```
<form method="POST">
  <select name="sex_select" id="sex-select">
   <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Sex</option>
   <option value="1">Male</option>
   <option value="0">Female</option>
  </select>

  <div name="ageValues[]" id="age-slider">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Created two hidden inputs

```
<input type="hidden" name="ageMin" value="" id="ageMin-input">
<input type="hidden" name="ageMax" value="" id="ageMax-input">
```

Set the values of the inputs when the slider values changes

```
var ageslider = document.getElementById("age-slider");
var ageMin = document.getElementById("ageMin-input");
var ageMax = document.getElementById("ageMax-input");

ageslider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  ageMin.value = values[0];
  ageMax.value = values[1];
});
```